# Make Windows 7 always connected with USB wireless

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, wireless-networking

As title says, I need to make one Windows 7 computer to always connected to network because this particular computer shares its printer, and its owner is not always there.

I have tried to set the computer not to turn off USB devices and set the power profile to Always On, but after a few moments, we always lost its signal, and someone must go to his room to login into his computer, even though its screen is not blanked out, then wait while Windows connect to the access point.

Any idea how to make it always online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Device Manager and make sure the network adapter isn't set to turn off.  The default setting is to allow it to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Install Printer using LPR port. It will install printer as Local Printer. Let me know if don't know how to install Printer as Local Printer attached with Network Computer using LPR.